# How to catch global errors on React Native app?

Tags: reactjs

We are creating a mobile App using React Native. We would like to catch all the errors that can be raised from inside the app.

What is the best option to handle this?

Previously with javascript technology we override the window.onerror function with our own method.

Thanks!

We tried to add error catch to some components

Comment: You can check out something called ErrorBoundries.

https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.